# Cloak or mirror all links from one website to another?

Tags: html, domain, url, forwarding

I have 2 domains, e.g. `www.domain1.com` & `www.domain2.com`.
I want to redirect visitors from `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.com`
without the users knowing that they are going to `www.domain2.com`.

So far, the easiest solution is domain cloaking, which achieves the above.

Now, I'd like it so that every time someone accesses domain1 and gets redirected to domain2 under a cloak, when they move their mouse over a link or click on it, it doesn't display `www.domain2.com/directory`, but either a static `www.domain1.com` link or a mirror of the directory, but displayed as `domain1.com/directory`.

Is this impossible? The situation is annoying and if circumstances allowed, I wouldn't be doing this at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by [Domain Cloaking](http://www.abcseo.com/seo-book/domain-cloaking.htm) you mean using IFRAMES, it is impossible.  When you use an IFRAME, the web browser is still getting the content off the original site, not yours.

What you need to do is implement some kind of proxy which can mangle the data on the way through, and rewrite the domain.  Its not practical to advise further on how to do this without knowing the OS you need to use, but privoxy and squid can both be made to do this.